# Does this poster convey a “Frenchy” look?

Tags: typefaces, terminology, posters

In the brainstorming to give a visual identity to the [French Language & Usage](https://french.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange, one of the [proposals](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like-idees-de-conception-visuelle-du-s/195#195) is to base the design on vintage posters such as this one:

[image: “Chat Noir” vintage poster]

But I am afraid that we are a strongly biased audience and would like to ask you whether this kind of graphics feels “Frenchy” to you. Do you associate this visual identity with France, French people, or the French language?

<sup>I understand that brainstorming and idea gathering are (understandbly!) off-topic here, so I hope this question passes muster.</sup>

Comment: I do, but I went to art school. It is french, but it evokes a specific time period for me.

Comment: I concur: French and Art Deco, specifically.

Comment: @Lauren, I think that's more Nouveau than Deco.

Comment: you're probably right. I'm an English major; I never studied art. :)

Comment: When you're storming the Brainstille, pitchforks in hand, such distinctions are of little consequence. At least nobody suggested a tumbril... :-D

Comment: Shouldn't the *Brainstille* be the *Bastille*?

Comment: ..Well, I dont see any baguette's in the poster...

Comment: Sorry...when I think "Frenchy" I think this: 
http://southernflair.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/frenchy.jpg

Comment: More like *fin de seicle* or *belle epoche*

Comment: @horation *siècle* and *époque*

Comment: I don't have those keys :) and it is spelled `horatio` lol

Comment: @horatio sorry for the name… but it's also letter ordering and spelling (apart from accents)

Comment: I was riffing on the fact that spelling correction posts always have spelling errors. NP and thanks for the corrections

Comment: Even being French, I can't help much with the question, but there is a typo, it's written 'poëtes' where you should read 'poètes'.

Comment: Except that it used to be a correct spelling. The Littré dictionary (1877) has *poëte*, indicating that the *¨* is there so it is pronounced in two syllables.

Comment: So it was said "po-e-ete"? That sounds surprisingly clunky and staccato for French.

Comment: @Lauren it's “po-ete”

Comment: But doesn't the umlaut indicate that the vowel is pronounced twice? Like naïve in English? (Nai-eve) Without the umlaut, "poete" is already two syllables in French. I don't understand your first comment.

Comment: The umlaut just indicates that the vowel is pronounced as itself, rather than combined. So it's poh-ette rather than peut (or however you'd write that phonetically).

Comment: @horatio: See [Muphry's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry's_law).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The discussion on the FL&U meta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like-idees-de-conception-visuelle-du-s) shows the community strongly rejects the obvious symbols and has affinity for the antique, so if you were my client I'd probably lean in the direction of the late-19th Century lithograph look, like the one you show. There are great Lautrec lithographs that could provide inspiration, but it's that hand-drawn, quirky typography that sells the look. Pick the color palette from posters of the period, such as your example or this one:

[image]

Comment: nitpick: I'd label that as lettering rather than typography given that it's hand rendered. ;)

Comment: Bruno, my pet nit, is feeling picked on. Now I'll have to give him an extra bowl of comfort food.

Comment: @Alan I'm leaning towards this as well.

Answer (score 2):

The romantic Paris most people think of is late 1800s/early 1900s, of which these posters are reflective of. Other artistic styles that can help convey “French” would be Impressionism and Art Nouveau.

Answer (score 2):

Perfect, it definitely looks Frenchy to me! (note that I'm not French :-))

P.S.: when I see that poster I almost hear Edith Piaf singing ...